# I want to code a program which can generate phone numbers(9 digits)

Tags: javascript

Phone number must be 9 digits (something like this 597257593)also I have to type first 3 digits (**597** 582167) and after that program has to generate last six number randomly.

I'm using Html and Javascipt.

```
<body>
    <h3 id="numbOutp">5</h3>
       
    <button onClick="pushFullNumb()">
        generateNumber
    </button>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var numArr = [""]

function makeRandomNumb() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    let stringedNumb = random.toString()
    numArr.join(" ")
    return stringedNumb    
}

function pushFullNumb() {    
  for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
    numArr.push(makeRandomNumb())
  }    
  return numbOutp.innerText = `597` + " "  + numArr.join("") 
}
```

after this code runs it can make first full number but I want to make all the possible numbers and give it to  element.

Thank you for any advice.

```js
var numArr = [""]

function makeRandomNumb() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    let stringedNumb = random.toString()
    numArr.join(" ")
    return stringedNumb    
}

function pushFullNumb() {    
  for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
    numArr.push(makeRandomNumb())
  }    
  return numbOutp.innerText = `597` + " "  + numArr.join("") 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>random</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="numbOutp">5</h3>
       
    <button onClick="pushFullNumb()">
        generateNumber
    </button>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want to generate each possible number? `597 ******`, are a lot of possibilities..

Comment: Yeah I want all of them, or at least some amount of them

Comment: there are 9^6 combinations

Comment: If you want each possibility, you can just loop from `0` to `999999`, for the first `100000`, pad a `0` on the left side. However, don't think any browser is gonna like this kind of actions.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want this for browser, I used html to visualise it... Thank u, but what u mean, I have to loop from 0 to 999999, for the first 100000, pad a 0 on the left side. Can u give me  code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

function getSomeNumbers(numsToGenerate) {
    first3Digits = "597"
    var allPhoneNumbers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numsToGenerate; i++) {
        allPhoneNumbers.push(first3Digits + getRandomInt(100000, 999999))
    }
    return allPhoneNumbers;
}

console.log(getSomeNumbers(10))
```

This prints in the console as:

```
[
  '597811491', '597377764',
  '597368701', '597587388',
  '597261293', '597408272',
  '597483819', '597210418',
  '597208802', '597493061'
]
```

Attaching them to HTML might be something like the below code. This would be if you wanted to add 10 numbers to a div for each button click.

```
function OnClick(){
    numbersNeeded = 10;
    var numbers = getSomeNumbers(numbersNeeded);
    for (i = 0; i < numbersNeeded; i++) {
        document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML += "<li>"+numbers[i]+"</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's quite the answer but, how can i add all of them in h3 element or even some element like <div> or <li>

Comment: @uski9992 at which point do you know how many you need to generate?

Comment: I've already added some code to 
determine how much number I need to generate

Comment: @uski9992 I added a code snippet of how to interact with html and these numbers. I hope it helps :)